# Getting value of auto incremented column in advance

Tags: asp.net

I am using the entity framework in asp .net. In the database, I have a table named Post in which id is auto incremented. Now, before adding a new post, I want to know which id will be assigned to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way for you get your goal is use a SQL Server Procedure get max id from your table post and plus 1 and you will get you next Id.. this is a waste way for get your goal

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM POST
```

For how using store procedures into EF read this link maybe help you

http://www.devtoolshed.com/using-stored-procedures-entity-framework-scalar-return-values

Comment: -1: the OP wants to know the new ID in advance. In this way he will know only after the submit.

Comment: Thats rigth, i read to fast @FrancescoDeLisi thanks for advice, i was testing here how get this goal.. is a bit tricky .. but is only way i think now.

Comment: -1 removed, this seems to be a good answer but be careful if there are concurrent Insert.

Comment: problem in this is , if a post having maximum  is deleted , then this method will not give answer. For example, suppose max id is 5. If that post is deleted , then after getting max and adding 1 to it will give 5. But id of new post will be 6. @danywalls